# Bisecting a 3D object into two equal volume objects - 2

Tags: mathematics, geometry, three-dimensional, dissection

Given the following 3D object and means of an unmarked ruler
to draw lines on its surface define a straight cut that will split it into two objects with the same volume.

Hint: It seems to have at least four solutions. There might be six.

Let me know if an additional view of the object is required.

[image]

Some examples of marks with an unmarked ruler are presented as black lines in the drawing. They are examples and not any suggestion for a solution.

Comment: Are the black lines intentional?

Comment: @Bass The black lines are intentional and just examples of type of marking on surface that may be made to help  with the selected bisecting. This is a result of some questions about what is allowed (was this you?).

Comment: Can we assume that the shape is made up from three cuboids? For example, are lines AB and CD parallel, is corner A constructed from three right angles, are points A,E,S all on one straight line, etc.?

Comment: Yes. On top of the large cuboid two smaller are placed at the corners - as the drawing supposedly should/hopefully depict.